# unsplash background url not working

Tags: css

So I am using unsplash for some images for my html page. Whenever I am including the backgground url I am not seeing it in my html page. I am receiving my images from https://unsplash.com/

I am just finding a picture right click copy image url and pasteing it into my body background url but I am not seeing any image background what am I doing wrong?

```
body {
    background: url(https://unsplash.com/?photo=vZlTg_McCDo);
    background-size: cover;
}


#content {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25%;
}
```

Comment: You're taking that udemy class too? I have the same problem, did you figure out how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use background-image: instead of background:

Comment: have you tried it for your self? Doesn't work it needs to be an image url from unsplash.com I need a high resolution picture

Comment: background-image:url(https://unsplash.com/?photo=vZlTg_McCDo); for reference as well

Comment: I thought of the link to image, otherwise that property will not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

According to their [API documentation](https://source.unsplash.com/), your image URL should be of the following syntax

```
https://source.unsplash.com/{PHOTO ID}/{WIDTHxHEIGHT}
```

Here is the modified form of the code in your question

```css
body {
    background: url(https://source.unsplash.com/vZlTg_McCDo/1600x900);
    background-size: cover;
}


#content {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25%;
}
```